# Placement of searchbox

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'd like to know , is it possible to change the placement of searchbox and place it inside the list on the top ?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. It is necessary to use [**Insert-Form Control-Combobox**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/menu/insert_form_control.html) instead of [**Data - Validity**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/12120100.html) and write several subroutines to control the visibility and position of this control, filling in its properties Linked Cell, Source Cell Range and others